# Cloning an image from MacBook Air to MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, backup, macbook-pro

I am getting a mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro. I currently have a mid-2011 11" MacBook Air.

I will be purchasing a Crucial M4 512GB SSD for the Pro and I want to clone my existing Air's HDD before I give it away. Can I use Carbon Copy Cloner to make an exact image from the current Air SSD running 10.8.2 to the Crucial and then pop in in the Pro or will there be driver issues?

I know I can use Time Machine, but it's a little more of a round-about way if CCC (or SuperDuper or plain old `dd`) is capable of doing the job in one swoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be a driver issue as long as the OS version on your Macbook Air is newer than the pre-installed OS version number on the Macbook Pro.

Comment: Are you sure? This MBP isn't retina, but I've read reports of 10.8.2 (latest) clones not booting on rMBPs

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. iMessages freaked out for a while, but it randomly started working. Everything else seems fine.